# Error with Spring AppRoleAuthentication - URI is not absolute

Tags: java, spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I'm trying to retrieve secrets from vault using the AppRole authentication. But I get the error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

What I do is create a vaultEndpoint then depending on the method choosen I use token authentication or AppRole authentication. There's no issue with the token authentication, however whenever I try to retrive a secret or even get the vaultToken to login with AppRole the *URI is not absolute* error occurs.

I 've seen in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html that an URI is absolute when it specifies a scheme otherwise it is relative. But I think that my URI is specifing a scheme.

So I'm a bit lost here.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong ? Or why I get this error ?

I use spring-vault-core-2.2.0.RELEASE

Here's my code :

```
VaultEndpoint ep = VaultEndpoint.create(host, portInt);
    if (scheme != null) {
        ep.setScheme(scheme);
    }

    if (authMethod.equals("token")) {
        vaultTemplate = new VaultTemplate(ep, new TokenAuthentication(token));

    } else if (authMethod.equals("appRole")) {

        RestOperations restOperations = VaultClients.createRestTemplate();

        AppRoleAuthenticationOptions options = AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.builder()
                .roleId(AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.RoleId.provided(roleId))
                .secretId(AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.SecretId.wrapped(VaultToken.of(secretId))).build();

        vaultTemplate = new VaultTemplate(ep, new AppRoleAuthentication(options, restOperations));
    }
  }
```

I have the same error if I try to get the vaultToken :

```
            RestOperations restOperations = VaultClients.createRestTemplate();
        AppRoleAuthenticationOptions options = AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.builder()
                .roleId(AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.RoleId.provided(roleId))
                .secretId(AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.SecretId.wrapped(VaultToken.of(uncryptedSecretId))).build();

        AppRoleAuthentication appRoleAuth = new AppRoleAuthentication(options, restOperations);
        VaultToken appRoleToken = appRoleAuth.login();
```

Here is the error :

```bash
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:98)
    at org.springframework.vault.client.VaultClients.lambda$createRestTemplate$0(VaultClients.java:128)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:742)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:586)
    at org.springframework.vault.authentication.AppRoleAuthentication.getSecretId(AppRoleAuthentication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.vault.authentication.AppRoleAuthentication.getAppRoleLoginBody(AppRoleAuthentication.java:344)
    at org.springframework.vault.authentication.AppRoleAuthentication.createTokenUsingAppRole(AppRoleAuthentication.java:201)
    at org.springframework.vault.authentication.AppRoleAuthentication.login(AppRoleAuthentication.java:191)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, the issue was how I instanciated the restTemplate.
I added the spring context library to my project and implemented the *AbstractVaultConfiguration* class. This class contains a *restOperations()* function that solved my problem.

This is how I solved the issue :

```
public class AppRoleAuthenticationService extends AbstractVaultConfiguration {

private String roleId;
private String secretId;
private String host;
private String scheme;
private String port;

public AppRoleAuthenticationService(String roleId, String secretId, String host, String scheme, String port) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
    this.secretId = secretId;
    this.host = host;
    this.scheme = scheme;
    this.port = port;
}

@Override
public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
    int portInt = Integer.parseInt(port);
    VaultEndpoint ep = VaultEndpoint.create(host, portInt);
    if (scheme != null) {
        ep.setScheme(scheme);
    }

    return ep;
}

@Override
public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication() {

    AppRoleAuthenticationOptions options = AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.builder()
            .roleId(AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.RoleId.provided(roleId))
            .secretId(AppRoleAuthenticationOptions.SecretId.provided(secretId)).build();

    return new AppRoleAuthentication(options, restOperations());
}
```

}

And then just use this class :

```java
AppRoleAuthenticationService appRoleAuth = new AppRoleAuthenticationService(roleId, 
      uncryptedSecretId, host, scheme, port);
VaultEndpoint vaultEp = appRoleAuth.vaultEndpoint();
ClientAuthentication auth = appRoleAuth.clientAuthentication();

vaultTemplate = new VaultTemplate(vaultEp, auth);
```